# Is QProcess::finished signal called when the process is killed?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess

As the title says, do you know if a killed process in Qt calls the finished signal?

From the docs [finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) and [kill](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill) is not clear to me.

Even if I could do a test, I would like to know an official answer, so that I am sure the behaviour is the same in every machine, in every operating system etc. etc.

Comment: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/3fe74b76fd0eaf39d4c6681e2edca5adbf107883/src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp

Comment: "I would like to know an official answer" - In this case you should contact the code maintainers.